# How can I turn an image into a popover button?

Tags: html

I have the following code for a basic popover button, which works as it should:

```
<button type="button" class="popover-dismiss" data- container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="This is a popover.">
    popover test
</button>
```

(And this script):

```
<script>
    $('.popover-dismiss').popover({
        trigger: 'focus'
    })
</script>
```

I want to modify this popover so that instead of a button, the message is prompted when an image is clicked. My image code is:

```
<img src="./images/c4dlogo.png" alt="c4d" class="icon" c4d">
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, and how should I modify the above code in order to do so?

Comment: Put 4 or more spaces before it in your question, and it will appear as code. I'm on mobile so I think my edit was slightly sloppy but perhaps you can clean it up a bit now.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! It looks fine the way you did it.  I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me. Please see the example below.

```js
$('.popover-dismiss').popover();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://placehold.it/150/09f/fff.png?text=c4d-Logo" alt="c4d" class="icon popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="This is a popover." data-placement="right">
```